# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load_img'

Tags: python, image, numpy, tensorflow, dataset

[image]I am a beginner to this and I am unsure how to overcome this problem. Cleary variable img is a numpy array. I am unsure how to amend this.

I have tried allot but I doubt it is relevant.

If there is more required, feel free to ask.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you overwrote the import for image.

Answer (score 0):

image is already a numpy array.
just put:

```
x = image
```

rest you can keep the same
If you are passing image as a filepath or string, your code will work

Comment: Hey Shen an thankyou! I changed the line on 4 (x = image.image_to_array) to "X = image" like you said. Doing that I got another error stating: AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'load_img'

Comment: yes that function is for PIL image instance, However, your image is already a numpy array.
You can do the following if you still want to preprocess using keras, this will convert your array data to PIL image  
```
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(img_data)
```
https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#loadimg-function

Comment: Thank you. It is much appreciated. I dont want to overstep but I got another error saying: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'img_data' referenced before assignment.
I will try googling it in the meantime but I am not familiar with these errors at all.

Comment: referenced before assignment occurs when you use a variable without declaring it

Comment: you need to be more careful about where you assign values to variables, and what you assign.  You need to be as picky about this as the computer.